# thread stopped after detach

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I use the codes below to test detach (in ubuntu18.5, g++7.5):

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void long_process()
{
    ofstream ofs("test.log", ios::app);
    ofs<<"long process start" <<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3*1000)); //wait 3 seconds
    ofs<<"long process end" <<endl;

}

int main()
{
    ofstream ofs("test.log", ios::app);
    ofs << "main start" <<endl;
    std::thread th(long_process);
    th.detach();
    ofs << "main end" <<endl;                                                                                                                                                               }
}
```

But in the test.log, I only see 3 lines, it seems long_process stopped after detach.

> main start
> main end
> long process start

I think the result of detach should be:

> main start
> main end
> long process start
> long process end

If I change **detach** to **join**, it works.

> main start
> long process start
> long process end
> main end

I don't know why.

**changed to thread_local and dynamic, but not work either**

```
void long_process()
{
    thread_local ofstream *ofs = new ofstream("test.log", ios::app);
    *ofs<<"long process start" <<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3*1000));
    *ofs<<"long process end" <<endl;

}

int main()
{
    thread_local ofstream ofs("test.log", ios::app);
    ofs << "main start" <<endl;
    std::thread th(long_process);
    th.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));                                                                                                                               ofs << "main end" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Note: On some operating systems (Like Windows) threads keep running after process termination/main thread ends (return from `main`). On other operating systems (like Linux) all threads are killed when the process terminates.

Comment: "`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000))`" - is not a synchronisation mechanism. You may be *increasing* the chance that the thread gets to run to completion before the program ends, but you are in no way guaranteeing it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks , Jesper.  "On some operating systems (Like Windows) ..." is there any c++ commitee article about it?

Comment: "is there any c++ commitee article about it?" - I don't know. But I doubt it. What happens to your threads after the main thread terminates is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (or implementation defined) territory, so I don't see why the standard would concern itself with it. Just `join()` your threads if you need to wait for them to finish, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 3):

After `detach` and `ofs << "main end" <<endl;`  your main thread exits and the program goes into its termination phase. In particular static storage duration objects are destroyed. When this part of the process has ended, then the possible actions of other still running threads become severely restricted.

In particular a thread may in that scenario only use standard library objects or functions which are specified to be usable in signal handlers. `std::ofstream` and other IO functions do not belong to those.

So your use of `std::ofstream` in the thread, unsynchronized with the return from `main`, has undefined behavior.

If you do use `detach` you should always make sure that you have some manual synchronization/termination mechanism before `main` exits, for that reason. If you do not have such a mechanism, use `join` instead.

Comment: Yes.  FWIW, when I run this code on MY machine, I don't even see the "long process start" message.  It's a race to see whether the message can be issued before the resources are freed.

Comment: Maybe also note that whether threads keep running or are killed when the process terminates, differs between operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I change it to thread_local and dynamic, but it doesn't work either, do you know why?

Comment: @ques The storage duration of your variable doesn't matter (and I didn't say anywhere that it would). You can't to use these standard library facilities at all in this termination phase.

Answer (score 0):

In the main thread, you are waiting for 1000ms. Meanwhile, the detached thread prints "long process started" and sleeps for 3000ms. During that time, the main thread wakes up and ends the process.